# Custom Post type Ajax search results

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to return search results without reloading the page, using ajax.

I followed some tutorials, but i can't find a way to return the results, it loads, stops, but doesn't return anything.

If i output the response as an alert it actually returns something, part of the site header, i have no idea why.

i'll be grateful if someone knows what is wrong with my code.

```
<div id="search-container">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="search" name="ajax-search" id="ajax-search">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buscar">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search-container form').on('submit', function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $input = $form.find('input[name="ajax-search"]');
    var query = $input.val();
    var $content = $('#content')

    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'myAjax.ajaxurl',
        data : {
            action : 'load_search_results',
            query : query
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $input.prop('disabled', true);
            $content.addClass('loading');
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            $input.prop('disabled', false);
            $content.removeClass('loading');
            $content.append( response );
        }
    });

    return false;
})
});
```

---

```
function ajax_search_enqueues() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 

'/assets/js/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-search', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_search_enqueues' );
```

---

```
function load_search_results() {
    $query = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : '';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        's' => $query
    );
    $search = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $search->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    else :
       echo "Nada encontrado";
    endif;

    die();         
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_search_results', 'load_search_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_search_results', 'load_search_results' );
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No, i don't get any error

Comment: Open dev tools panel and review the XHR response from the server.  Or confirm the PHP is getting the proper data with a dump in your `load_search_results` function.  If the PHP is receiving the Ajax request, review in the console to ensure the JS is handling the response correctly.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? This is exactly what I am looking for, but tried your code without success!